# Single value tensor set value?

Tags: pytorch

So if I have a tensor with a single value I can access the element with:

```
tensor.item()
```

But how can I change it?

Will:

```
tensor.item() = 3.0
```

work, I don't think so.

```
tensor[0] = 3.0
```

Isn't an option either for a single value tensor.

I can like divide the tensor by itself and then multiply it by the value I need to set but this looks like an ugly hack (as well as creating a new tensor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inplace operation like [`fill_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.fill_.html):

```
tensor.fill_(3.0)
```